# Automate Microsoft SQL Server query runs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using a Microsoft SQL Server. What I am trying to do is automate the query runs.

I have a `.sql` file with queries in it, which returns a set of data.

I just have to change one line in the `.sql` file and execute it over like 100 times, but I realize that this is very repetitive.

Also, every time I run it, I need to export the data into an Excel file.

So, at the end of this process, I need to get 100 Excel files.

Is there a way to go around doing this?

Comment: What exactly do you need to change in that script?

Comment: Sounds like a job for the **Integration Services** (SSIS)

Comment: You should try SSIS.

Comment: You could also write a powershell script if you don't have SSIS